# Incorrect output in deletion of array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I was writing a code for deleting repetitive elements in an array/list our teacher asked us to do so by replacing the elements with 0 and then send the 0s to end of list/array. The part to convert repetitive elements to 0 was successful but I am facing problem in sending the 0s to the end. The required code is

```
i=0
while i<n:
    if l[i]==0:
        k=i
        while k<n-1:
            l[k]=l[k+1]
            k=k+1
    i=i+1
```

Here `l` is the list and `n` is length of list/no. of elements in `l`.

Using `l=[2,1,1,1,3]` which converts `l` to `[2,0,0,0,3]` this code returns `[2,0,3,3,3]`,
which according to me should return `[2,3,0,0,0]`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], this doesn't do what you show (there is no assignment to zero or checks against 1), so it's definitely NOT correct.

Comment: What do you mean by *The required code is*?

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking for repetitive elements that come after one another. You are not handling the case where repetitive elements are not located correspondingly

```
l=[2,1,1,1,3]
j = l.copy()
for x,y in enumerate(l):
    if l.count(y) > 1:
        j[x] = 0

result = [nonZero for nonZero in j if nonZero!=0] + [Zero for Zero in j if Zero==0]
print(result)
```